# Continuous random variable on [0,1]

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable defined on the interval $[0, 1]$ with density function $ f_X (u)=c(1-u^2) $ for a suitable constant $c$. Find $c$, and so find the expectation and the variance of $X$. Also find the density function of the random variable $Y = X^2$

I got $\int_{0}^{1}c(1-u^2)du=1$ so $c=\frac{3}{2}$.

$E(X)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{3}{2}u(1-u^2) du=\frac{3}{8}$

I am stucked here and not sure if the results are right

Comment: I got $c=\frac{3}{2}$ and $E[x] = \frac{3}{8}$.

Comment: For variance, you can use $Var(x)=E(x^2)-E(x)^2$

Comment: Why are you stuck at the variance ?  Don't you know the formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of $c$ is wrong. If you show how you calculated $c$, I can help you find the mistake.

---

Your *method* for calculating $E(X)$ is correct, but your result is wrong because $c$ is not calculated correctly.

---

To calculate the variance of $X$, you can use the formula available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Continuous_random_variable)

---

To calculate the density of $Y$, it's easiest to calculate the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ first.